# From differential form to vector fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, singularity-theory

In page 13 of this course https://www.sissa.it/fa/download/publications/remizov.pdf
from the equation
$$
(F_x+pF_y) dx + F_pdp=0 \qquad (*)
$$
I do not understand how we can get
$$
\dot x =F_p, \quad 
\dot p = -(F_x+pF_y)  \qquad (**).
$$

($F_j$ denotes the derivative wrt $j\in \{x,y,p\}$)

As far as I understand, $(*)$ is an equation where $dx,dy$ are linear form (differential 1-forms), while $(**)$ defines vector fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (*) you are looking for vector fields $X=(u,v)$ with
$$
Mu+Nv=0,
$$
using $dx(X)=u$, $dp(X)=v$. This can be interpreted as an orthogonality condition. Thus
one trivial solution is to rotate $(M,N)$ by 90° to get $(u,v)=(N,-M)$ or $(u,v)=(-N,M)$. You can also scale by any other non-zero factor (function).

The resulting ODE system, with $\dot y=p\dot x$, gives solutions $x(t),y(t),p(t)$. On segments where $x(t)$ is monotonic it can be inverted, and then also $y$ and $p$ can be obtained as functions of $x$.